# How do I open 2 files side by side for comparison in atom editor

Tags: atom

This really is a struggle This freaking editor doesn't wanna let me open two files alongside each other for comparison very easily I give up trying to figure out how to do it Anyone can help?

Comment: I believe you’re asking about panes. [Ctrl]+[K] then an arrow key to specify where that pane should go may give you what you need. Alternatively, there’s the [split-diff](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff) plug-in …

Comment: You may want to use Meld or Kdiff3 instead. They are specifically suited for this purpose.

Comment: I guess I should be able to change the behavior of atom to open files in new tabs when I click on them in the left pane tree unless they're already open in a tab That would be good Now I have no control what pane they open in

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mupchrch/split-diff/raw/master/demo.gif shows a demo.

[image: Screenshot]

You need to open the command palette and enable split diff.
In my case i e.g. get:
[image: Diff of generator results]